# How do I output a Laravel 4 query builder query as an array?

Tags: php, laravel-4

If I perform the following query:

```
$lookupConnection = DB::connection(PZ_CONNECTION)->table($this->createLookupTable);
$lookupConnection->addSelect($lookupField);
$lookupConnection->where($searchField['data_lookup'], '=', $searchArray[$searchField['js_name']]);
$goodData = $lookupConnection->get();
dd($goodData);
```

This will work, and display an array containing an object.

```
Array(1) {
    [0] => 
    object(stdClass)#225 (2) {
    ["foo"] => string(3) "bar"
    }
    }
```

My problem is this, how do I access elements of the object without knowing what the element is?

I mean, the field is stored in $lookupField, however, I cannot run:

```
echo $goodData[0]->$lookupField
```

And if I try

```
echo $goodData[0][$lookupField]
```

I also get an error.

But if I try

```
echo $goodData[0]->foo
```

Then it works. But thats no good, as I don't know until runtime what the contents of $lookupField will be. I need to either output the query as an array, or access the object data via a variable, but I don't know how.

Comment: What errors do you receive?

Comment: You can perfom json encode and then json decode to get plain array instead of array of object. Then your can flatten the array or loop over to find property.

Comment: Ah, the problem was that I wasn't actually using $lookupField, I was using $anObject->$lookupfield[$n]. So the actual line would be $goodData[0]->$anObject->lookupField[$n] If instead I added 
$lField = $anObject->lookupField[$n], I could then do $goodData[0]->$lField

Answer (score 1):

Works fine in my Laravel project:

```
$ php artisan tinker
[1] > $field = 'title';
// 'title'
[2] > $p = Promotion::all();
// object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)(
// 
// )
[3] > $p[0]->$field;
// 'Test Promotion'
```

Or with the query builder:

```
$ php artisan tinker
[1] > $field = 'title';
// 'title'
[2] > $q = DB::table('promotions');
// object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder)(
//   ...
// )
[3] > $q->addSelect('title');
// object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder)(
//   ...
// )
[4] > $p = $q->get();
// array(
//   0 => object(stdClass)(
//     'title' => 'Test Promotion'
//   )
// )
[5] > $p[0]->$field;
// 'Test Promotion'
```

Comment: Thats using Eloquent ORM. I am using the query builder.

Comment: @FacebookAnswers The ORM uses the query builder under the hood. See my edit.

Comment: I've added an answer as the issue was slightly more complicated than I had originally posted. However, I have +1ed your answer because it is useful. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the problem was that I wasn't actually using

```
$lookupField
```

I was using

```
$anObject->$lookupfield[$n]
```

So the actual line would be

```
$goodData[0]->$anObject->lookupField[$n]
```

If instead I added

```
$lField = $anObject->lookupField[$n]
echo $goodData[0]->$lField
```

then that would work.